# How to get data from CKEditor 5 instance

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I know that for CKEditor 4, you can get the textarea data like this:

```
var content = CKEDITOR.instances['comment'].getData();
```

How is this done for CKEditor 5?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can find the answer in the [Basic API](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/basic-api.html) guide.

Basically, in CKEditor 5 there's no single global editors repository (like the old `CKEDITOR.instances` global variable). This means that you need to keep the reference to the editor that you created and use that reference once you'll want to retrieve the data:

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        editor.getData(); // -> '<p>Foo!</p>'
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

If you need to retrieve the data on some other occasions (who would read it just after initializing the editor, right? ;)), then save the reference to the editor in some shared object of your application's state or some variable in the scope:

```
let theEditor;

ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        theEditor = editor; // Save for later use.
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );

function getDataFromTheEditor() {
    return theEditor.getData();
}
```

See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2h2rq5u2/

**EDIT:** If you need to manage more than one editor instance, see [CKEDITOR 5 get editor instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575534/ckeditor-5-get-editor-instances/48682501#48682501).

Comment: and using "var theEditor" would be a better choice instead of "let theEditor" preventing "Identifier has already been declared" error in multiple loadings

Answer (score 4):

Declare a global variable and then use editor.getData(). Something like this:

```
var editor;
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#editor'))
    .then(editor => {
        editor=editor;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Then, in your event handler, this should work:

```
editor.getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into what felt like a unique situation where I was loading multiple instances of `CKeditor5` on a page but I also had features to dynamically `add/remove/rearrange` text areas that had editors applied to them.

Creating an array that contained all the instances was manageable but also a bit more complicated to keep track of when `adding/removing/rearrange` editor instances.

I instead decided to obtain the innerHTML of the editor instances by selecting all .ck-editor__editable classes and iterating over them to check the content.

```
document.querySelector("button[type='submit']").addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const domEditableElements = document.querySelectorAll('.ck-editor__editable');
  for (let i = 0; i < domEditableElements.length; ++i) {
    let elementData = domEditableElements[i].innerHTML
    if (elementData === '<p><br data-cke-filler="true"></p>') {
      console.log(`Field ${i} is empty`);
    }
  }
});
```

Console logging indicated that ck-editor stored `<p><br data-cke-filler="true"></p>` in blank fields.