# CKEditor5 Get Plain Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I know how to get data using CKEditor5 API as it's mentioned in documentation and on another SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46816098/how-to-get-data-from-ckeditor5-instance).

However, how could I get the Plain Text? I tried following but it returns nothing.

```
alert($(editorObj.element).val());
```

Interesting Note: Even following code returns nothing if TextArea is bind with CKEditor

```
alert( $("#editor").val());
```

But if I don't bind TextArea with CKEditor then it works fine.

Any solution or feedback would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use the dev console to take a look at the actual dom and see which element contains your actual data.

Comment: It doesn't update editor's element data until we call updateEditorElement function. But that too updates the formatted text not the plain text.

Answer (score 6):

CKEditor 5 does not expose such a method but you can use one of the utils of the [`@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard`](http://npmjs.com/package/@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard) package – [`viewToPlainText()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_clipboard_utils_viewtoplaintext.html#viewToPlainText).

It's used by the clipboard feature to set the `text/plain` flavour in the clipboard when the user copies some content from the editor.

To use it you'll need to use CKEditor 5 from source (because this function is not exposed publicly). You can read about that in the [CKEditor 5 Framework's Quick start](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/quick-start.html) guide.

You can use this method to stringify the entire editor's view:

```
import viewToPlainText from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard/src/utils/viewtoplaintext';
import ClassicEditorBuild from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic/src/ckeditor';

ClassicEditorBuild
    .create( element )
    .then( editor => {
        // Will get the stringified content.
        console.log( viewToPlainText( editor.editing.view.getRoot() ) );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error.stack );
    } )
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok, I found a workaround:

```
var plainText = $(editorObj.getData()).text();
```

Until we get a proper solution or a method exposed by library, I hope this workaround will work.

Answer (score 0):

We use `this.editor.editing.view.getDomRoot().innerText;`