# I'm having problem getting data from ckeditor textarea

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I'm having problem getting the textarea(ckeditor) value. This is the script line :

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.1.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

This is my textarea code :

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.FullNews, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Parag" })
```

This is my scripts section code :

```
 ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#Parag'))
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });



    function loadData() {
        debugger;
        var head = $("#Header").val();
        var para = CKEDITOR.instances.Parag.getData();
        document.getElementById("Para").innerHTML = para;
        document.getElementById("Head").innerHTML = head;
        readURL(document.getElementById("newsImage"));
        $("#previwe_before_publish").modal("show");
    }
```

When i debug it in browser, i get the error "**Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined**" in the line :

```
var para = CKEDITOR.instances.Parag.getData();
```

I searched over the internet but couldn't find the solution for it. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I haven't defined that. I have only used the cdn link that I have mentioned above. Nothing more than the code above. Can you suggest me what more should I do ?

Comment: @charlietfl I did. same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CKEDITOR.instances** simply is not defined in CKEditor 5. According to this section of the CKEditor 5 [FAQ](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/faq.html#what-happened-to-the-global-windowckeditor-how-to-list-all-instances-of-the-editor):

> **What happened to the global window.CKEDITOR? How to list all instances of the editor?**
>
> *By default, CKEditor 5 has no global registry of editor instances. But if necessary, such feature can be easily implemented as explained in the [Stack Overflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48682501/1485219)*

However, it *is* defined in [CKEditor 4.](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#property-instances) Refer to the StackOverflow answer referenced in the CKEditor 5 documentation, or shift to CKEditor 4 for your code to function.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked. Since I found out now that the question has already been asked before, should I delete this question ? I mean what's the general convention in stackoverflow ?

Comment: @Shiwa mark this answer has correct, upvote it if it is clear and logical / helped you easily, and then someone can mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: Okay. I marked it as correct. But I couldn't upvote it due to my low reputation. Are you sure I'm not supposed to delete this question ?

Comment: @Shiwa StackOverflow has a duplicate flagging system so that if a question like this is asked by someone else and they end up here instead, they can be routed to the duplicate. I have flagged the question and a moderator will eventually come through and accept the question as duplicate.

Comment: If you flagged as a duplicate you should NOT have added an answer!

Comment: @StephenMuecke I flagged this as a duplicate after I added an answer, per the request of the OP. So perhaps you mean that I should not flag this as duplicate if I added an answer?