# CKeditor5 instance in variable to textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea, ckeditor5

Hi community this is my first post, apologise if I missing something:

I have Ckeditor5 instances in a variable editors like this example:

[CKEditor 5 – get editor instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575534/ckeditor-5-get-editor-instances)

As in the example editors is a javascript array with multiple CKeditor5 instances, my idea is to create this instances just once, when I load the website then every time I load content with texareas I would like to pass those CKEditor instances in "editors" array to those text areas.

something like:

```
document.getElementById('textareaid') = editors.instance1
or
document.getElementById('textareaid') = editors[instancename]
```

Bottom line how can I pass ckeditor5 instance to a text area?

also im adding the console output for reference.

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aizbE.png)

Thanks for the help

Comment: what is the question? did you try out what you are suggesting?

Comment: Passing the instance in the var to a textarea. Note the suggestion does not work.