# How to set data on an already created editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to set data to 3 nos. of already created editors which I am unable to do.

I tried pt. no. 2 to set data which is happening on a newly created editor and not to the existing one.

1. Below is where i am creating my 3 editors:

```
create_editor: function () {
            window.editors = {};
            document.querySelectorAll('.editor').forEach((node, index) => {
                ClassicEditor
                    .create(node, {
                        //removePlugins: [ 'Heading', 'Link' ],
                        toolbar: ['bold', 'italic', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote', 'Heading'],
                        //placeholder: 'Type the content here!'
                    })
                    .then(editor => {
                        //console.log(editor);
                        window.editors[index] = editor
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        //console.error(error);
                    });
            });
        }
```

2. Below is where i am trying to set my data to all my 3 existing editors:

```
set_editor: function (elem, data) {
            ClassicEditor
                .create(document.querySelector('#' + elem))
                .then(editor => {
                    editor.setData(data);
                })
        }
```

The data are stored in a local storage and I want to retrieve them and set them to my already 3 created editors which currently is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you need to get an instance of existing ClassicEditor to edit it.

As provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575534/ckeditor-5-get-editor-instances/48682501#48682501), you can store your instances in a global variable (like you are already doing, but instead of index store `element.id` as key)

Also from your comments, it is clear that you are facing race condition between editor create and editor set, so instead of saving the editor in `window.editors` save the promise, that way you can wait for editor create to finish before setting the value.

```
create_editor: function () {
    window.editors = {};
    document.querySelectorAll('.editor').forEach(node => {
        window.editors[node.id] =
        ClassicEditor
            .create(node, {
                //removePlugins: [ 'Heading', 'Link' ],
                toolbar: ['bold', 'italic', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote', 'Heading'],
                //placeholder: 'Type the content here!'
            })
            .then(editor => {
                //console.log(editor);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                //console.error(error);
            });
    });
}

set_editor: function (elem, data) {
    window.editors[elem].then(editor => editor.setData(data));
}
```

Comment: I will try that and let you know.

Comment: hi Avcs, I tried and your code worked same to mine. Your code created another editor and the data was shown there. I want to show the data to my existing editor. how is this possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575534/ckeditor-5-get-editor-instances/48682501#48682501 please follow this answer, it provides a way to store instances and fetch, based on element id

Comment: hey Avcs, thanks for the link. i was able to set the data now but i am able to do it for the last editor and not for all the other 2 before it. can you help? also, i tried your edited code and i am getting "window.editors[elem] is undefined", though console.log(window.editors) return the correct objects of 3 editors.

Comment: Maybe you are facing a race condition? Create method is asynchronous

Comment: i am totally clueless now buddy.

Comment: Ok race condition means, you start an asynchronous event and try to access the result before the completion of the asynchronous event

Comment: Ok but in my case my both the functions are independent to each other. I dont see a reason why i have to use async. Plz correct me if im wrong.