# How to updateElement() in CKEditor 5?

Tags: ckeditor5

I'm trying to update some initialized CKEditors but it doesn't work.

In CKEditor 4 it was:

```
for(var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances) 
    CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].updateElement();
```

Does not work for CKEditor 5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My answer will depend on [ClassicEditor](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-classic_classiceditor-ClassicEditor.html) but it will also work with the [InlineEditor](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-inline_inlineeditor-InlineEditor.html) and [BalloonEditor](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-balloon_ballooneditor-BalloonEditor.html).

The [`ClassicEditor.create()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-classic_classiceditor-ClassicEditor.html#static-function-create) function returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that will be resolved with the editor instance. There is no longer any global variable that holds created editors. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46819396/3388924.

If you initialized the editor on a `<textarea>` element (which should be inside a `<form>` element), the value of the `<textarea>` will be updated automatically when the form is submitting. You can see the [source code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/blob/v10.1.0/src/editor/utils/attachtoform.js#L33-L62).

Of course, you can update the element manually. See the [`ClassicEditor.updateElement()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_editor-classic_classiceditor-ClassicEditor.html#function-updateElement) method. I also prepared an online demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pomek/k1wp093n/

Keep in mind that `editor.updateElement()` function in the future release will be renamed to `editor.updateSourceElement()`. See [`ckeditor/ckeditor5-core#129`](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/pull/129)

Comment: $('.ck-editor__editable')[3].ckeditorInstance.updateSourceElement() seems to work (jquery et al.)

Comment: Is there no way to trigger `updateElement` this without timeout? I would like to have changes instandly when something happens in the Editor, I could imagin there should be any kind of "editor has changed" event or something,